# How many digits in $2^{2^{22}}.$

Tags: number-theory

How many digits are in $2^{2^{22}}$.
Not understanding how to start.
I have observed a pattern that no. of digits increases by $1$ as the exponent of $2$ increases by $3$.

Comment: Well observed. The ratio is actually $\log10/\log2=3.32193\cdots$, because $2^b=10^d$ ($b$ binary digits vs $d$ decimal digits) implies $b\log2=d\log10$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. The number of digits of $n$ in base $b$ is related with the logarithm in base $b$  of $n$:
$$\lfloor\log_{b}(n)\rfloor+1.$$
In your case $n=2^{2^{22}}$, hence the number of digits is
$$\lfloor2^{22}\log_{b}(2)\rfloor+1.$$
So if $b=2$, we have $2^{22}+1=4194305$ digits, if $b=10$ then we have
$1262612$ digits.

Answer (score 1):

To find the number of digits for a given number $x$ (where $x\in\mathbb{N}^+$), use:

$$\text{D}_x=\lfloor\log_{10}(x)\rfloor+1$$

So, when $x=2^{2^{22}}$:

$$\text{D}_{2^{2^{22}}}=\lfloor\log_{10}\left(2^{2^{22}}\right)\rfloor+1=\lfloor2^{22}\log_{10}\left(2\right)\rfloor+1=1262612$$

Comment: Wow! Is there a paper in which I can see the proof, or maybe some related awesome things like that? : D

Comment: @FourierTransform: there is no need for a paper, this is simple algebra.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, I bet you once woke up and thought "oh, sure! The number of digits is the log base 10, plus 1". Come on.

Comment: @FourierTransform: that's indeed one of the first things you learn about decimal logarithms: the integer part of the logarithm is the number of digits of the number. I can't remember what time it was.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose it has $n$ digits. Then $10^{n-1} \leq 2^{2^{22}} \leq 10^n -1 < 10^n$. Now take logarithms.